# How to call findViewById(R.id.textView) in another class than MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context

I am new to Android.
**I am trying to refer a View by Id from a separate class than MainActivity.**

**Note**: My app has single activity.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)//Activity Oncreate callback
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) //Oncreate Options_menu callback
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.option1:
    //Here am calling a method from another class

    SecondClass secondClassObject=new SecondClass();
    secondClassObject.method1();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class SecondClass {
    public void method1(){
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv1.setText("");
    }
}
```

How to refer to the textView by ID in the SecondClass? How to set the context as MainActivity in this SecondClass?

Comment: The second class is not just another java class. It extends AppCompatActivity, you shouldn't initialize the object yourself, the android system does it for you. You should use a button with an intent to open the other Activity. `TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)` this throws an error because the layout hasn't been created and the view doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, now I updated the question and its explanation. Can u suggest me how do i do it?

Comment: Pass (Context)MainActivity as parameter in the constructor or method.

Comment: @PeterMmm can you show it as an answer?

Comment: Be careful when saving activity in external objects especially global ones.
This is going to lead into memory leaks.

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos are you refering to the first answer by Thomspon sparta? Then how do you suggest I do this?

Comment: @SayanSen yes exactly I will add the comment there.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Normally the `Activity` or `Fragment` is responsible for the UI. You shouldn't have code in another class that calls 'findViewById()`

Comment: @DavidWasser actually another method in another class is a callback/event listener which keeps getting triggered async to the main thread, hence i need to show some data from the callback itself. I cant return back to the main thread i guess.

Comment: In general in this case, the callback should simply call a method in the `Activity`. The `Activity` has access to the UI elements. Your architecture is broken.

Comment: thats not working, because to call a method in Activity the method has to be either static or non static. Non static method cannot be called without an object and creating an object of Activity is not normal, static method cannot call the UI elements since they are non static

Answer (score 0):

Add an Activity parameter for your method

```
public void method1(Activity act){
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv1.setText("");
}
```

From your activity define an Activity variable `Activity act;` so as to use it across other functions .Assign a value of your Activity to the variable `act=this;` and finaly use it on the function you want.

```
                public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                Activity act;
                 @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)//Activity Oncreate callback
                    {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        act=this;
                    }
                @Override
                    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) //Oncreate Options_menu callback
                    {
    act=this;

                        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
                    switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.option1:
                    //Here am calling a method from another class

                    //SecondClass secondClassObject=new SecondClass();
                    //secondClassObject.method1();
                    SecondClass secondClassObject=new SecondClass();
                                secondClassObject.method1(act);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

you can also pass the parent layout view

```
  public void method1(View act){
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv1.setText("");
  }
```

And call it like so

```
 SecondClass secondClassObject=new SecondClass();
  secondClassObject.method1(findViewById(R.id.your_parent_layout));
```

Avoid using passing Activity method if its not absolutely necessary to avoid possibilities of memory leaks.

Comment: But now it throws error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" at line "tv1.setText("");"

Comment: Be careful when saving activity in external objects especially global ones. This is going to lead into memory leaks.

Comment: @SayanSen Thats because your findViewById returns null.
I suggest you run the debugger or add some logs and see what is wrong

Comment: check your activity's XML to make sure textView with the id "textView" exists

Comment: But i cant follow this answer since it may acually lead to memory leaks

Comment: @Thompsonsparta it exists. Still it is showing as if doesnt exist. When i refer the same view from MainActivity it exists. So somehow the Context is not getting passed properly.

Comment: @Thompsonsparta   calling it 
 as "secondClassObject.method1(findViewById(R.id.your_parent_layout));" is not displaying any such view on the activity(or app screen).

Comment: @Thompsonsparta if i call it as "secondClassObject.method1(act);" it says "(android.View.view) cannot be applied to (android.app.ACtivity)"

Comment: see  'public void method1(View act){
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv1.setText("");'
  }